# How to read specific lines of a file into a 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I am a chemistry PhD student "attempting" to write code in python

I have an input file like this below that I will be reading in

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP
20000000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
2
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 51.577
0 51.048
1.06653 47.9335
ITEM: ATOMS id type x y z
5 1 15.6042 48.7947 36.9084
27 1 18.4619 1.23863 36.2611
ITEM: TIMESTEP
20005000
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
2
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
0 51.577
0 51.048
1.03417 47.9658
ITEM: ATOMS id type x y z
5 1 16.183 47.8777 37.7161
27 1 17.9296 50.8771 36.5807
...................
```

I want to read the file and extract the certain point of the array which I have handled so far with this code

```
in_name = raw_input('Name of input: ')    
R_file = (open(in_name, 'r')) #readfile 
for j, line in enumerate(R_file):
    if j%11 == 10:
```

Where I will be getting the line that starts with 27 every time for a reference.

However I can't seem to append the one line into a multidimensional array.

I eventually want an array of floats like this

```
[[27.00], [1.00], [17.9296], [50.8771],[36.5807]]
```

When I would read in all the data not worrying about the line I was reading I would do something like this

```
lines = [line.split() for line in R_file]
```

which I would then convert using

```
for x in range(length):
    for y in range(len(lines[x])):
        lines[x][y]=float(lines[x][y])
```

How can I doing something like line.split() for just one line at a time and then append it to an array for my desired line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an empty list before you start looping over the lines of the file. Then, at each iteration of the loop where you have data (I guess on the last line of every 11-line set?), split the line into its components as you were before (`.split()`). It also makes more sense to convert the data to floats at this point, in my opinion. Finally, `.append()` this new line of data to the list you declared at the beginning. This gives you a list of lists of numbers, i.e. effectively a 2-dimensional array.

Something like this:

```
file_location = # wherever your data is
data = []
with open(file_location, 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        if index % 11 == 10:
            data_line = [float(num) for num in line.split()]
            data.append(data_line)
```

Now, `data` looks like this:

```
[[27.0, 1.0, 18.4619, 1.23863, 36.2611],
 [27.0, 1.0, 17.9296, 50.8771, 36.5807]]
```

Additional note: I have used the `with open(...) as f:` construction. If you're not familiar with it, this basically is a shorthand that saves you from having to `.close()` the file when you're done with it.